# How do I send data from my Raspberry Pi 3 to my SQL Server? (Python)

Tags: python, sql-server, raspberry-pi

I want to know how to send data from my Pi to my SQL server.

My Pi has a PIR Motion sensor that when/if it detects motion, this is done with some python code and GPIO. When it detects motion it currently counts off by 1, says "motion detected", and then prints the date-time in this format `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss:sssssss`.

What I need it to do now is send that date-time to my SQL server, so that I can then use SQL Queries to find metrics on how often the sensor was triggered. I don't think this is that complicated but so far I have not found much to help me out.

Is there something I need to do on my SQL Server? (Windows Server 2012 R2)
What should I look for in terms of python code to use?

Comment: googling `python ms sql` should get you to some tutorials

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/03/11/python-and-data-sql-server-as-a-data-source-for-python-applications/